# is there a way to host latest SPFx on SharePoint 2019?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spfx, spfx-webparts

I know that the supported SharePoint Framework version for the SharePoint 2019 is SharePoint Framework v1.4.1 but I wonder if there is a way to bypass this ?

For example:

- Can I upload the js files in dist folder of an SPFx 1.11 Web part onto SharePoint 2019 and used them in Sharepoint 2019 Classic UI pages ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not. SPFx relies on support from files residing in the SharePoint hive, which is shipped as part of the product.

Comment: Maybe I should stick with the classic UI on SP2019 then and use React / other JS Framework in my own custom solution in Visual Studio ?

Comment: That is a potential option.